# How to check if a div has a video track attached?

Tags: dom, video, html5-video, twilio

I am using the twilio to enable an in app video chat. I am attaching the audio and video tracks of each user to separate container divs. How can I check whether a given div already has a video track attached to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

If you can target the `<div>` with some sort of id or css selector, then you can do so within the `<div>` element too. So, with the following HTML:

```
<div id="localVideo">
  <video></video>
</div>
```

Then you can get the `<div>` with [`document.getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) or [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) and then search within the `<div>` using [`element.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector).

```
const div = document.getElementById('localVideo');
if (div.querySelector('video')) {
  console.log('There is a video!');
} else {
  console.log('No video yet.');
}
```

`element.querySelector` returns the element you are searching for if it exists or `null` if it doesn't.

Let me know if that helps at all.